# Like statment not returning correct values

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having a little problem finding a query to do what I want.

Im using Jquerys autocomplete to search for job ID.

Currently the code I'm using is:

```
$keyword = "%" . (int) $_GET['term'];
$sql = $DB->prepare("SELECT JID, SiteName FROM jobs WHERE CID = :cid AND `JID` LIKE :term ORDER BY JID DESC LIMIT 6");
```

when the code runs it only returns IDs 1 and 11

I want is so any ID beginning with 1 is displayed eg

1,10,11,12,13,14,15 ... 100 etc

Any ideas how I solve this?

Comment: Is it always intended to be a 1 digit beginning that you are matching, or could it vary (22 for example 22,221,229,2299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change that

```
  $keyword = "%" . (int) $_GET['term'];
```

to

```
 $keyword =  (int) $_GET['term']. "%" ;
```

you are cheking numbers which ends by 1 , like that you will check numbers wich starts by 1.

this would be better thought if you using pdo

```
 $keyword =  (int) $_GET['term'];
 $params = array("$keyword%");
 $sql = $DB->prepare(...........);
 $sql->execute($params);
```

Comment: That works great! 
so just to clarify. `"%" . (int) $_GET['term'];` would be search last. `(int) $_GET['term'] . "%"` would search the beginning and `"%" .(int) $_GET['term'] . "%"`would search anywhere in the string?